# What is the name of an operator which transforms a finite ordered set into a tuple?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, order-theory

Is there a name for such an operation in mathematics, which takes a finite ordered set $S$ (e.g. $\{a, b, c, d\}$), and creates a tuple $T$ (e.g. $(a, b, c, d)$), performing "concatenate" operation?

By a tuple, I mean $T \in S^{cardinality(S)}$

Thanks.

Comment: Do your "ordered sets" allow repeats? If so, then I think the answer may be "no operation is needed because we call your ordered sets 'tuples'."

Comment: can repeat.  An ordered set $S$ isn't a member of  $S^{cardinality(S)}$, so is not a tuple.

Comment: To me, this sounds like the question "What is the name for the function which takes a natural number such as $2$ and returns the corresponding real number $2$?"  Does there *need* to be a name for it?  Even if the rigorous definitions differ slightly (*which I'm not convinced they do in your case*) the end result is that it is clearly doable in an obvious enough fashion that the exact mechanics of it and name of such a transformation need not even warrant a mention.

Comment: As for what I *would* call it if forced to refer to it, I would say that you "*reinterpret*" the object.

Comment: @JMoravitz: No, since there is no natural order on "things", this is not the same as moving from $1+1$ in one monad to another.

Comment: What do you consider a finite ordered set to be? Is it a subset of a set which has a natural ordering, or is it a "finite ordered set" also know the order of elements in the set?

Comment: @Joppy any order, which also decides the order between the elements in a tuple.

Comment: @Tim How do you formalise what a "finite ordered set" is? For example, is a finite ordered set a pair $(S, f)$, where $S$ is a finite set, and $f$ is an injective function $f: S \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Joppy A finite set with a total order.